# replacing componentDidMount with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I was going through React Hooks docs and it mentioned

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
>   componentWillUnmount combined.

Suppose I have a class component right now where in componentDidMount I am doing something like this

```
  componentDidMount() {
    MapboxGL.setTelemetryEnabled(false);
  }
```

As far as I can recall, Component did mount is only called once in lifecycle?

If I were to use react hooks then it would be something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
   MapboxGL.setTelemetryEnabled(false);
  });
```

This would call my function everytime state changes in react functional hooks component? Wouldn't it be redundant to call  `MapboxGL.setTelemetryEnabled(false);` to call this everytime? when you only want to do it once component have mounted?

React docs have showed how `useEffect` can replace multiple lifecycle methods but I am still unable to comprehend how react hooks can replace componentDidMount?

Also, Just a side note question, Can you make a full fledge app using hooks (something like foursquare or instagram?)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a dependency array for it to know when to recall this hook. An empty dep array will only call it once aka "on mount". And if you don't provide a dep array then it will just be called on every re-render.

```
useEffect(() => {
   MapboxGL.setTelemetryEnabled(false);
}, []);
```

Comment: you can only have one hook in functional component? or can we have multiple useEffect hook in a functional component?

Comment: you can have multiple, but they should never be conditional and the order of the hooks should always remain the same

Comment: And to answer your other question, yes you can build full-fledged apps using hooks. Most devs seem to be moving towards functional components & hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag and if the flag is false/true then only perform that action. something as simple as this

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (something) {
    MapboxGL.setTelemetryEnabled(false);
    setSomething(false) 
    }
  });
```

or if you only need hook once, you can do what Matt have suggested

```
useEffect(() => {
   MapboxGL.setTelemetryEnabled(false);
}, []);
```